# Comparar dos cadenas, aparentemente son iguales

Tags: php

Estoy intentando comparar `2 string`. el primero lo obtengo de un `array`, el segundo lo obtengo de leer un directorio. El problema esta en que estoy intentando comparar que el nombre del array coincida con el de el archivo que esa leyendo y son idénticos.

Cadena proveniente de un array longitud de: 30 
algo está cambiando.mp3   //elemento del array

Archivo leido de Directorio longitud de: 23 
algo está cambiando.mp3   //fichero

lo estoy haciendo con este código para compararlos y siempre me arroja que es falso. no sé porque son diferentes.

```
echo  "<br>Cadena proveniente de un array longitud de:  ".strlen(($arrayPosiciones[$x])). " ".  ($arrayPosiciones[$x]);
echo  "<br>Archivo leido de Directorio longitud de:".strlen(($d)). "  ".($d)  ;
```

creo que es por problema de acentos o algo así. he intentado de muchas formas. Incluso al array le puse el `htmlentities()` ya que los elementos que tienen tilde estaban mal codificados.

Con esto se arregla el problema, y los elementos que no se les muestra la tilde, se arregla.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($arrayPosiciones); $i++){
    $arrayPosiciones[$i]=htmlentities($arrayPosiciones[$i]);
}
```

que puedo hacer?
estoy recorriendo un directorio y comparo que el archivo actual sea igual al que esta en el $arrayPosiciones

```
$ruta=$_REQUEST['ruta'];
$dir =scandir($ruta);
foreach($dir as $d){
 if(substr($d,-3)=='Mp3' || substr($d,-3)=='mp3' || substr($d,-3)=='MP3' ||  substr($d,-3)=='WMA' || substr($d,-3)=
  for( $x=0; $x<count($arrayPosiciones); $x++){
    if($arrayPosiciones[$x]==$d){ echo "iguales"; }
.
.
.
```

Comment: En los ejemplos que muestras, una cadena tiene longitud 23 y la otra 30, desde ahí ya no son iguales. Si crees que es problema de tildes, usa **utf8_encode** para convertirlos a ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 3):

Si tienes problemas de codificación de caracteres, tienes que cambiar toda la codificación de caracteres de apache, php, mysql, html:

**En apache:**

[httpd.conf]

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

en algunas versiones de apache no se encuentra AddDefaultCharset en el lugar habitual y tienes que buscar $cfg['DefaultCharset'] = '';
en toda la instalacion o variables similares y cambiarla por $cfg['DefaultCharset'] = **'utf-8'**;

**En php:**

[php.ini]

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation=On
mbstring.func_overload=0
```

Si estas usando una versión superior o igual a php 5.6 estos parametros estan obsoletos:

```
mbstring.internal_encoding
mbstring.http_input
mbstring.http_output
```

y basta con poner **default_charset = "utf-8"**

**Si usas mysql** toda la collation de Base de datos y tablas debe ser **utf8 - utf8_spanish_ci** y en la conexión:

```
$Conex=new mysqli(.....);
$Conex->set_charset("utf8");
```

Por ultimo tus **html** debe tambien configurar el utf8 con la siguiente linea:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Esto funcionara perfectamente en linux pero si usas windows y tratas de escribir archivos a disco veras que no funciona (porque windows usa otra codificacion). Es entonces cuando hay que recurrir al gran repertorio de funciones que tiene PHP para codificación de caracteres, en este caso iconv. Ejemplo:
al escribir en disco;

```
 $nombre="ññ.txt"
    $f2=fopen(iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1",$nombre),"w"); 
    fwrite($f2,$texto);
    fclose($f2);
```

ó al leer de disco;

```
$tam=filesize(iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1",$nombre));
```