# Problema UPDATE con AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

Quiero actualizar los datos de un formulario mediante AJAX (jQuery 1.10.2) y la respuesta pasa por el error.

**HTML**

```
<form name="formulario">
  <p id="identificador">9</p>
  <input id="opcion-1" type="radio" name="opcion" value="1">Opción uno
  <input id="opcion-2" type="radio" name="opcion" value="2">Opción dos
  <input id="opcion-3" type="radio" name="opcion" value="3">Opción tres
  <textarea id="texto"></textarea>
  <button onclick="update()">Update</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Variables
var form   = document.formulario;
var id     = document.getElementById('identificador');
var radio  = document.getElementsByName('opcion');
var text   = document.getElementById('texto');


// Devolvemos la hora
function getUpdatedAt() {

  var d = new Date();
  var day = d.getDate();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var minutes = d.getMinutes();
  var seconds = d.getSeconds();

  return year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

}


// Gestionamos el UPDATE
function update() {

  // Guardamos los valores que vamos a enviar
  var valor_1 = parseInt( id.textContent );
  for(var i=0; i<2; i++) { // radio.length = 2
    if (form.radio[i].checked) {
      var valor_2 = parseInt( form.radio[i].getAttribute('value') );
    }
  }
  var valor_3 = text.value;
  var valor_4 = getUpdatedAt();

  // Mandamos los datos al servidor
  $.ajax({
    url: 'classes/update.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { id: valor_1, opcion: valor_2, texto: valor_3, updatedAt: valor_4 },
    success: function(response) { console.log('success'); },
    error: function(response) { console.log('error'); }
  });

}
```

**PHP**

```
// Nos conectamos
$db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT) or die("Error de conexión");

// cambiamos el juego de caracteres a UTF-8
$db_connection->set_charset("utf8");

$data = array();

// Hacemos el UPDATE de el input radio 'opcion' y el textarea 'texto' relacionados con el id N
$sql = "UPDATE nombre_tabla SET opciones = ".$_POST["opcion"].", textos = ".$_POST["texto"].", updated_at = ".$_POST["updatedAt"]." WHERE ids = ".$_POST["id"]."";

// pon el resultado en la variable result
$result = $db_connection -> query($sql);

$row_goal_detail = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$data[] = $row_goal_detail;

echo json_encode($data); //devolvemos los datos


$db_connection->close();
```

El código que está descrito en la pregunta es un código simplificado para hacerlo más legible. A continuación está la respuesta que pinta la consola del código sin simplificar:

**console.log(response)**

```
Object {
  readyState: 4,
  responseText: "<br />↵<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error x… 11.759 alunos na Educação de joven' à la ligne 1",
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK"}
  abort: (e)
  always: ()
  complete: ()
  done: ()
  error: ()
  fail: ()
  getAllResponseHeaders: ()
  getResponseHeader: (e)
  overrideMimeType: (e)
  pipe: ()
  progress: ()
  promise: (e)
  readyState: 4
  responseText: "<br />↵<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>↵<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\new-g\classes\update.php on line <i>24</i></th></tr>↵<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>↵<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>↵<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>144312</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\new-g\classes\update.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\update.php <b>:</b>0</td></tr>↵<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>152720</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysqli-fetch-assoc' target='_new'>mysqli_fetch_assoc</a>↵(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\new-g\classes\update.php ' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\update.php <b>:</b>24</td></tr>↵</table></font>↵[null]Erreur de syntaxe près de 'o fim de março de 2014 foram matriculados  11.759 alunos na Educação de joven' à la ligne 1"
  setRequestHeader: (e,t)
  state: ()
  status: 200
  statusCode: (e)
  statusText: "OK"
  success: ()
  then: ()
  __proto__: Object
```

Comment: ¿Qué respuesta es la que obtienes?

Por cierto, el console.log del on error lo tienes con una "a" delante de "console".

Comment: @JVLobo el código que he puesto en la pregunta estaba 'reducido' para simplificarlo lo máximo posible, con esta reducción me he comido un valor a actualizar: la fecha y hora.
El error sin mandar la fecha y la hora me estaba devolviendo este error por consola:
Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}.
Añadiendo después la función que extrae la fecha y la hora la consola me devuelve:
"Object {readyState: 4, responseText:
"Erreur de syntaxe près de '18:18:37 WHERE id = 9' à la ligne 1", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}"
He actualizado el código de la pregunta.

Comment: Una diferencia pequeña, pero veo en el código que es `WHERE ids =` y el error dice `WHERE id =` . Puedes mostrarnos el query generado?

Comment: @Shaz, acabo de publicar la respuesta al final de la pregunta. Era demasiado extensa para colocarla por los comentarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero debes saber que así nunca te va a guardar nada en base de datos ya que nunca executas el query:

```
$repuesta=$db_connection->query($sql);
```

Segundo; me parece que se va por el error porque le dices que va a devolver un json de respuesta:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

pero no de vuelves nada, solo cierras la conexión:

```
$db_connection->close();
```

y despues matas el proceso(esto es lo que esta mas equivocado ¿Como le va a contestar a javascript si le dices que se muera?).`die` es para terminar los procesos cuando hay un error (por ejemplo falla en la conexión a bd), no es para terminar los scripts en todo momento:

```
die();
```

El `die` debe usarse así:

```
$db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT) or die("Error de conexión");
```

Saludos

Comment: Bueno, el die no necesariamente "debe" usarse así, es solo una forma de usarla. De hecho no debería usarse en la medida de lo posible, sería mejor lanzar excepciones.

Comment: Es correcto, y en la excepción manejar el error para que el script realmente responda algo, ya que con die no respondería a javascript.

Comment: @abrahamhs, @Shaz; acabo de actualizar los errores que tenía en el PHP en el código de la pregunta. muchas gracias, ando muy pez en PHP. Aunque habiendo realizado los cambios sugeridos no he conseguido realizar el UPDATE. Puede que tenga que ver con el formato que estoy enviando la fecha y la hora.

Comment: te esta marcando error en la linea $row_goal_detail = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); ¿porque no revisas bien la documentación de esta función? Estas usando estilo orientado a objetos y debe ser así:
 $fila = $db_connection->fetch_assoc()
Tambien parece que tienes el problema de codificación de caracteres de php; revisa mi respuesta en este post para corregirlo ya que eso tambien causa problemas al guardar en base de datos: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7336/comparar-dos-cadenas-aparentemente-son-iguales/8087#8087 Saludos

Comment: Otra cosa de la que no me había dado cuenta, es que al ser un update no debes usar $db_connection->fetch_assoc() ya que eso es para selects revisa esta url para que veas como se hace correctamente:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp es el Example (MySQLi Object-oriented)

Comment: @abrahamhs **solucionado**! al __quitar la función fetch_assoc()__ a realizado el UPDATE correctamente.
Muchísimas a todos!

Comment: dale en la palomita porfa, eso me ayuda